# combining multiple dataframes based on nearest index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have multiple (~5) dataframes each of which have data from a given source like the one below:

```
>>> d.head()
Out[18]: 
                      SOURCE      B1        S1          B2         S2  
Time                                                                                                             
2017-04-03 00:01:00.221  J     1114.73    2000000     1117.47    2000000    
2017-04-03 00:01:02.701  J     1114.10    2000000     1117.47    2000000    
2017-04-03 00:01:02.701  J     1114.10    2000000     1117.44    2000000   
2017-04-03 00:01:02.902  J     1114.80    2000000     1117.44    2000000   
2017-04-03 00:01:08.413  J     1114.76    2000000     1117.44    2000000
```

I want to combine all of them on time, and take the max B1 and Max B2 (from all sources) at a given time. Given that time runs into microseconds, I have very few exactly overlapping rows, so I want to join based on time which is within a given width of each other (say 1 second). I am wondering if there is a better way to do this than below which combines 2 dataframes at a time based on nearest index:

```
d1['1 Index'] = d1.index
temp = d1.reindex(d2.index, method='nearest')
df_merge = pd.concat([temp, d2], axis=1)
```

I have to do the above 5 times to create a combined df_merge. But the above method may have mergers which are more than 1 second apart which is undesirable. In addition, in each subsequent merging, there is a choice of merging on first of the second dataframe's index.

Comment: Can you `pd.asof_merge()` unless you need the absolute closest

Comment: With that I still have to do 5 joins, and the problem with asof is that it is left join not outer. So i will lose all data that doesn't match in a given join, but might have matched in later joins.

Comment: Right, but shouldn't you have a basis? A data frame that's has samples more often that you want to set as the main one?

Comment: There are too many unknowns in this problem.  As I was messing around with ideas, I realized that I don't know many parameters that I need to know.  I could spend a long time listing all the ideas I have and constructing a bunch of sample datasets and **guess** what it is you are trying to do.  **OR** you can do the leg work for us and provide sample data, show us what the end result should look like, explain the logic to get the result, and finally, show us what you've tried so far.  As it is, this is a poorly written question.

Comment: Sure, I'll update shortly.